# sql запрос выбрать нужные слова с названия по списку слов из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server, текст, split, select2

Есть столбик с названием продукта. Из названия нужно убрать лишнее слова. Список лишних слов находится в другой таблице.

На данный момент всё это делаю в Екселе с помощью Макрос.

Возможно так в Microsoft SQL SERVER 2014 ?

Oколо 300 слов в списке. Одно слово в одной ячейки. Названия всегда стандартные

Comment: около 300 слов в списке

Comment: 1. Microsoft Sql server 2014. 2. Одно слово в одной ячейки. 3. Названия всегда стандартные

Comment: так если слово состоит из 8 слов, его нужно разбить на 8 столбиков ? и как тогда эти столбики соеденить с стоп таблицей ?

Comment: Дайте точное и однозначное определение термина "слово" - чтобы невозможно было придумать контрпример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё отлично, но медленно...

А как теперь сделать так, что бы видны были все исходные столбики и к ним добавить столбик с обрезанным названием. ?

Вот ещё мой вариант:

```
declare @t table (s varchar(max));
declare @w table (w varchar(100)); 
insert into @t

 select pavadinimas from import_excel;

insert into @w
select slova from Slova;

select
 rtrim(c.x.value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'))
from
 @t t cross apply

 (select cast(cast('' as xml).query('sql:column("t.s")') as varchar(max))) a(s) cross apply

 (select cast('<w>' + replace(a.s, ' ', '</w><w>') + '</w>' as xml)) b(x) cross apply

 (
  select

   wl.w + ' '

  from

   (select row_number() over (order by (select 1)), w.n.value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(100)') from b.x.nodes('w') w(n)) wl(rn, w)

  where

   not exists(select 1 from @w where w = wl.w)

  order by

   wl.rn

  for xml path(''), type

 ) c(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Медленно и печально - но работает.

```sql
WITH cte1 AS 
( /* нумеруем имена */
SELECT LTRIM(name) + ' ' name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) namenum
FROM names
),
cte2 AS 
( /* делим имена на отдельные слова по пробелу */
SELECT namenum,
       1 wordnumber,
       CAST(LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name) - 1) AS CHAR) oneword, 
         /* предполагаем, что макс. длина имени менее 1000 */
         /* впрочем, её можно вычислить в ещё одном CTE */
       LTRIM(SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name), 1000)) slack
FROM cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT namenum,
       1 + wordnumber,
       CAST(LEFT(slack, CHARINDEX(' ', slack) - 1) AS CHAR), 
       LTRIM(SUBSTRING(slack, CHARINDEX(' ', slack), 1000)) 
FROM cte2
WHERE LTRIM(slack) != ''
),
cte3 AS 
( /* выбрасываем ненужные слова */
SELECT cte2.*
FROM cte2
LEFT JOIN words ON cte2.oneword = words.word
WHERE words.word IS NULL
)
/* и собираем обратно в имена */
SELECT STUFF( ( SELECT ' ' + RTRIM(cte3.oneword)
                FROM cte3 
                WHERE cte1.namenum = cte3.namenum
                ORDER BY cte3.wordnumber
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') name
FROM cte1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=1af71285aa9b6a7ae93fd8c4acb68070)

PS. `CAST` кажутся лишними, но без них fiddle матерился на несоответствие типов - а мне лень думать.